# D3DCompileFromFile unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors, directx-11

Im having a linker error while creating a simple directx code which uses the default effects11.lib. The error Im getting :

**Effects11.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3DCompileFromFile**

As I learned from some links that I am missing a d3dcompiler.dll. I included the d3dcompiler.lib in the project. But I am not sure how to link the dll to the project . Im new in these stuffs.

One solved his problem by doing this :

"The default Effects project was including the Windows dev kit (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0 for me). After putting the DirectX SDK path first, this problem was fixed"

But I dont know what he meant.

So please help me solve the problem. I really do not have time with the upcoming term project at hand. And I am new so please give me details.

Comment: What is exactly the problem after adding d3dcompiler.lib to the project?

Comment: The problem is given above I have linked to d3dcompiler.lib but still it can't find the function mentioned above.

Comment: Just a guess: `putting the DirectX SDK path first` means changing the order of linker search directories, so that correct d3dcompiler.lib is used. Try to search your computer for this file, if more than one is found, try each of them. Probably you need the library from DirectX SDK and not from another developer kit.

Comment: And how do I change the order of the linker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86) entry from the /Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Library Directories and insert it before all other library dependencies in Configuration Properties/Linker/General/Additional Library Dependencies.

BAM!

Comment: I'd like to know -why- this fixes it, if possible.

Comment: This was about a year ago so I can't remember fully, but I think it's because the dependencies below in Addition Library Dependencies will inherit the windowssdk library path

Answer (score 0):

I moved on to VS13 and it solved my problem , I thought the problem was because I included Effects11d.lib in relaesae mode. I had to include only Effect11.lib in release mode.